# MoveIt: Is there a trajectory-cache?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

For my current project on picking with a UR, I'm looking for a cache for planned paths. Some movements (e.g. from the put position back to a start position) are repeated for every object and the planning needs some time (around 2 seconds) which I'd like to save by storing plans in a DB (doesn't even need to be persistent) so that if I request the same start and end-joints I can look up the trajectory and execute it directly (assuming a constant collision environment).

Is there something available or do I have to implement it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252314/moveit:-is-there-a-trajectory-cache?/) by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi PickBot,

I am pretty sure there is no standard trajectory-cache available at this time. I have also had the need for something similar (but it had to be persistent) and have implemented it using .yaml files on disk and a pre-defined set of joint states as start/goal states. You might be able to find something on github for your application, but I don't know of any.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) on 2017-01-19**:
Thanks! Any hints on what you learnt during the implementation?

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-01-19**:
It's tricky to figure out exactly *when* a query is equivalent as the joint states naturally vary with to some degree, so you need some kind of threshold. Sometimes we would plan a very short path to a (close) pre-defined state to ensure the robot will be at that state when the trajectory starts.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-01-19**:
Also, if you do intend on storing the trajectories to disk, it's easiest to use rosbags. The implementation we wrote is online and can be found here: [apc16delft_motion](https://github.com/amazon-picking-challenge/team_delft/tree/master/apc16delft_motion/src) (note: we used yaml instead of rosbags)

**Comment by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) on 2017-01-19**:
That's also what I planned. I have a drop position and would generate a set of start points above the box so that I first plan to the closest start point and execute the stored trajectory afterwards.

**Comment by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) on 2017-01-19**:
Thanks for the link. I saw the delft run at the APC this year and even had a look at the ROSCON-slides but I didn't find code for the cache.